# How to find the size of a partially known name file in a partially known name folder in a known drive

Tags: python

The Python code below lets me read the file size.

```
import os
b = os.path.getsize("known_drive_name/folder_name_partial_known/file_name_partial_unknown_file_ext_known")
print b
```

But given the following conditions:

- I know the drive name;
- There is only one file inside the folder;
- I know the file extension;
- I don't know the file name (or I know only certain letters);
- I don't know the folder name (or I know only certain letters);

Can you help me build the code to find the size of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by tmoreau, you can use the glob module
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob

If you only want to match one file you can try :

```
import glob
import os
extension = ".gif"
drive = "/mnt/ssd0/"
dir_glob = "**/[0-9]/*"
paths = glob.glob(drive + dir_glob + extension)
if paths: # if the list is not empty
    print os.path.getsize(paths[0])
```

of course you will have to adapt the glob_pattern according to what you know of the directory names.

Comment: thanks paul.  This works.  i am yet trying to get the regex correct!

Comment: if you can share the information you have about the path I could probably help you.

Comment: why do I get"IndexError: list index out of range' error some time?

Comment: this is because the regex you use doesn't match any file, i'm editing the code so you don't get this error

Comment: Could you be more clear about your regex : what does the directory name contain, in what order, what is the drive name, do you want to search recursively in sub folders? what is the extension you want to match?

Comment: that is kind paul:  Here is the folder for which I want the regex: "\_1. AAAAAA 11Aaa15 11a11.11 (AA-AAA)"(A= upper case generic letter, a= lowercase generic letter; 1 = generic numeral)

Comment: yes!  recursively in subfolders: "\_1. AAAAAA 11Aaa15 11a11.11 (AA-AAA)"(A= upper case generic letter, a= lowercase generic letter; 1 = generic numeral)

Comment: \\folder_1\folder_2\_folder_3\_1. AAAAAA 11Aaa15 11a11.11 (AA-AAA).  recursive search in the last folder.

Comment: could you give an example? because your pattern looks like it contains a date and a could be ":" character and not a letter

Comment: "\\aerobytesprod\AerobytesLoad\_Failed Replays\_0. FAILED 17Nov15 07h29.58 (XY-XYZ)"  the first 3 folders are fixed and names known.  in the elast folder resides one file with .dat extension.  file size to be found recursively in the last sub folder with varying names. thanks.

Comment: this seems to work : " \*\*/_[0-9]. [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][0-9]5 [0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9] ([A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])/*" for this example : "~/folder1/_8. MONDAY 12Oct15 12h45.35 (UN-OBC)". however it is pretty much disgusting, I haven't found out how to match an exact number of letters using a glob like you can do it with regex (ex : "[A-Z]{2}") still you can use this until you figure it out.

Comment: thanks.  I am getting the hang of it.  I still have the "IndexError: list index out of range".  dont take too much trouble though! does it work in python 2.7 or only for 3?

Comment: no problem ! have you added the "if" statement I suggested? It works for me using python 2.7.6.